# Make Background Image position vertically center to left

Tags: css, background, background-image, css-sprites, background-position

I have a Image of my work,

[image]

I want the icons on the left should be in the same position but align center vertically...
Icons are of different sizes...
can this be possible via css what i want..??

Here's my code,

```
.iconSmall {
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-clip: padding-box;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-position: 2% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

<a href="index.html" style="background-image:url(images/001_56.png);" class="iconSmall">Beauty and Spas</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

until and unless all your icons are of same size that code is not going to align then as you wish.

but what you can do is

```
.iconSmall {
background-attachment: scroll;
background-clip: padding-box;
background-color: transparent;
background-origin: padding-box;
background-position: 2% 50%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

then have each of your list items another class as well like

```
<li class="iconSmall foodResturant">....</li>
.foodResturant {
background-position:1px 2px;
}
```

Comment: the icons size differ from each other like some icons have greater width lesser height and some have lesser width greater height, 1 or more icons get enlarged... so i cant use fixed width or background-size etc for it...

Answer (score -1):

Yes, that works fine. You only need to specify the positon and repeat:

```
.iconSmall {
    background-position: 5px center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 30px;
}
```

You might want to use pixels rather than percent. You can use the `center` keyword instead of `50%` if you like.

Tip: You can use more than one class on the elements, so that you can put the background images in the style sheet:

```
.iconSmall.beauty {
    background-image: url(images/001_56.png);
}

<a href="index.html" class="iconSmall beauty">Beauty and Spas</a>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/UrXA2/

Comment: this answer may not be useful to me as i want icons vertically center align to left...

Comment: @SaurabhLP: The icons *are* vertically centered, and placed 5 pixels from the left. You can naturally change the number of pixels to anything that you want. If you want them flush at the left edge, you can use the `left` keyword.

Comment: For this I have to arrange all the icons manually with different size to left that i dnt want... the icons and text are coming dynamic from DB how can i set it for every icon different left size..

Comment: @SaurabhLP: I dont get it... What are you trying to do, really?

Comment: I have a photoshopped image for it... Please have a look i want something like that... [RefImage](http://i.imgur.com/Cs5OW.jpg)

Comment: @SaurabhLP: Oh, you want it centered *horisontally* also... You can't center the image based on part of an element, so you would have to put the background image in an element by itself: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/UrXA2/1/

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.